# Wicket component by output markupid

Tags: wicket

Is there a way to get wicket component by its output markupid? I have ajax function to send two markupId-s and I want to get two components that printed these id-s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MarkupContainer` has an Iterator with his children. `Component`s have a method `getMarkupId()`. You could iterate over this iterator and check if a children a has the desired markup id.